# Android Auto Layout like iOS

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anybody tell me, Is there any way to create auto layout in android like iOS?
i find from a long time but not found correct answer. In iOS, auto layout is used to set all screen layout design, is it possible to do the same thing in android?

If yes, then how? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in android new layout named constraintLayout available. you can try that

Comment: i tried but it difficult to handle this time...

Comment: Other than that as per my knowledge there is no such layout available